# how to derive median from conditional median?

Tags: median

Let $m_{y|x}(y|x)=e^x$ denote the conditional median of $Y$ given $X$. What is the approach to derive unconditional median of $Y$---- $m_y(y)$? Any relationship between the conditional and unconditional medians?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: The unconditional median will be between the smallest possible conditional median and the largest possible conditional median

Comment: Thanks. Is there any reference to read? When is it possible for the median of conditional median=unconditional median, like mean and conditional mean?